# If(isnumber(search) vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table:

```
┌────────────────────────────────┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬─────┬──┬──┬──┬───┐
│               I                │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │   L │  │  │  │ S │
├────────────────────────────────┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼─────┼──┼──┼──┼───┤
│                                │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │     │  │  │  │   │
│ Mr John Smith                  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │     │  │  │  │   │
│ Mr Jack Paul and Mrs Jack Paul │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │     │  │  │  │   │
└────────────────────────────────┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴─────┴──┴──┴──┴───┘
```

My VBA code is:

```
Sub x()
    Dim TR As Long
    TR = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("L2:L" & TR) = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""MR"",I2:I" & TR & ")),""Dear Sir"","""")")
    Dim SS As Long
    SS = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("S2:S" & SS) = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Dear Sir"",L2:L" & SS & ")),""your banking facility"","""")")
End Sub
```

What I want is:

If in column `I` there are `Mr` and `Mrs` then column `L= Dear Sir/Madam`, and if `L= Dear Sir/Madam` then Column `S= your banking facilities`.

With Mr its works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 versions

**Version 1** As per your updated comments - Looping sheets with format as specified.

**Version 2** Where you can use a dictionary and a search term

**Version 1**

Structure for looping sheets and if customer search term varies (covered by ElseIfs)

At present set up to loop 2 sheets. I have set the:

1. `custNameColumn` : Expected customer name column = A
2. `salutationColumn`  Expected salutation column =  2 ("B")
3. `commentColumn` Expected banking comment column = 3 ("C")
4. `targetFirstRow` Row in each sheet where first customer name is = 2

These can be changed in the code but must be consistent across sheets.

It is **not** the most efficient method, but you couldn't use the Evaluate method as it is currently set-up so this is a an easy alternative rather than getting into more complicated code.

You can add additional `ElseIf` statements for more search terms e.g. `Master`

You can add more sheets to `sheetsArr`

```
Option Explicit

  Sub test()

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
        Dim targetRange As Range

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook

        Dim sheetsArr()
        sheetsArr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

        Const custNameColumn As String = "A" 'column where customer name is
        Const salutationColumn As Long = 2 'column where "Dear" goes
        Const commentColumn As Long = 3 'column where "Banking goes"
        Const targetFirstRow As Long = 2 'row where first customer name is

        Dim targetLastRow As Long
        Dim currentSheet As Long

        For currentSheet = LBound(sheetsArr) To UBound(sheetsArr)
          '  On Error Resume Next
            Set wsTarget = wb.Worksheets(sheetsArr(currentSheet))
          '  On Error GoTo 0
            targetLastRow = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, custNameColumn).End(xlUp).Row

            Set targetRange = wsTarget.Range(custNameColumn & targetFirstRow & ":" & custNameColumn & targetLastRow)

            Dim currentCell As Range

            For Each currentCell In targetRange

                If InStr(1, LCase$(currentCell), "mr ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 And _
                    InStr(1, LCase$(currentCell), "mrs ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

                    currentCell.Offset(, salutationColumn - 1) = "Dear Sir/Madame"
                    currentCell.Offset(, commentColumn - 1) = "Banking Facilities"

                ElseIf InStr(1, LCase$(currentCell), "mr and mr", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

                    currentCell.Offset(, salutationColumn - 1) = "Dear Mssrs"
                    currentCell.Offset(, commentColumn - 1) = "Banking Facilities"

                ElseIf InStr(1, LCase$(currentCell), "mrs ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

                     currentCell.Offset(, salutationColumn - 1) = "Dear Madame"
                     currentCell.Offset(, commentColumn - 1) = "Banking Facility"

                ElseIf InStr(1, LCase$(currentCell), "mr ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

                     currentCell.Offset(, salutationColumn - 1) = "Dear Sir"
                     currentCell.Offset(, commentColumn - 1) = "Banking Facility"

                ElseIf InStr(1, LCase$(currentCell), "miss ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

                     currentCell.Offset(, salutationColumn - 1) = "Dear Miss"
                     currentCell.Offset(, commentColumn - 1) = "Banking Facility"
                End If

            Next currentCell

        Next currentSheet

    End Sub
```

**Version 2:**

So you could put the `searchTerm` in a variable. Note I have used a dictionary to hold the Title and the associated salutation. You can just extend this dictionary for new items.

If you have multiple different search terms, I am not sure evaluate, used in this manner, is the right way to go about it.

To use `Evaluate` in this manner you want ranges of equal length so you can do away with `SS` and just use `TR`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub x()

    With ActiveSheet

    Dim TR As Long
    TR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim searchTerm As String

    searchTerm = "Mr and Mr"

    Dim salutationDictionary As Object

    Set salutationDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    salutationDictionary.Add "Mr", "Dear Sir"
    salutationDictionary.Add "Mrs", "Dear Madame"
    salutationDictionary.Add "Ms", "Dear Miss"
    salutationDictionary.Add "Mr and Mr", "Mssrs" 'keep adding here

    Dim bankingComment As String

    Select Case searchTerm

    Case "Mr", "Mrs", "Ms"  ' - singular cases add here
       bankingComment = "your banking facility"
    Case Else
        bankingComment = "your banking facilities"
    End Select

    .Range("L2:L" & TR) = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""" & searchTerm & """,I2:I" & TR & ")),""" & salutationDictionary(searchTerm) & ""","""")")
    .Range("S2:S" & TR) = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""" & salutationDictionary(searchTerm) & """,L2:L" & TR & ")),""" & bankingComment & ""","""")")


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: can i send my excel sheet with all names

Comment: i have tried your code and i am not having the expected results. may be you can help me if you have my excel sheet. what is your email address .thanks

Comment: i am sending the following link https://www.dropbox.com/s/harergtb4kr6mmo/TESTING2.xls?dl=0 .and results are shown .

Comment: expected result  should be as i have shown in the excel sheet.thanks for your help

Comment: version 2 works well. i would like to consider  this  Mr and Mr   result will be Dear Messrs and your banking facilities. thanks

Comment: sorry  it's version 1 not 2  my apologies

Comment: i am getting Dear Sir  for Mr and Mr  it should be Mssrs in version 1

Comment: I  have removed the surname and name of  the customer from column  A (example Jack Mr Smith and John Mr George to Mr and Mr .).It works when i remove the surname and name

Comment: The first version looks for Mr and Mr. If you need Mr * and Mr * that is more complicated.

Comment: can you do it for me please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you’re after this

```
Sub x()
    Dim TR As Long
    TR = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("L2:L" & TR) = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""MR"",I2:I" & TR & ")),""Dear Sir"","""")")
    Range("L2:L" & TR) = Evaluate("IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""MR "",I2:I" & TR & ")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""MRS"",I2:I" & TR & "))),""Dear Sir/Madam"","""")")
    Dim SS As Long
    SS = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("S2:S" & SS) = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Dear Sir"",L2:L" & SS & ")),""your banking facility"","""")")
    Range("S2:S" & SS) = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Dear Sir/Madam"",L2:L" & SS & ")),""your banking facilities"","""")")
End Sub
```

Comment: can i send you my excel sheets  with all my names

Comment: attach screenshots if it in your post and/or add some plain example to your post . but what about the code in my answer, did you try it?

Comment: how to send attachment

Comment: swearch the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for that. I never did that but I saw many did it

Comment: expected result should be as i have shown in the excel sheet.thanks for your help

Comment: your question code speaks about columns I, L and S while your drop box example shows columns A, B and C. So what's the truth?

Comment: originally  in my original  copy it's columns I,L,S there are lots of data in other columns that why  i have  curtailed it